# setOnSelectedItemListener not triggered for a Spinner in DialogFragment

Tags: android

I am trying to implement Spinner dropdown menu within a `DialogFragment`.

Although the Spinner is being populated with choices correctly, it is not able to trigger the `setOnSelectedItemListener` method for that instance of the Spinner. Hence, when the user selects a choice from the Spinner dropdown, the Spinner is not displaying the selected item and isn't triggering `onSelectedItem`.

Here is the code fragment:

```
public class DialogRegisterStudent extends DialogFragment {

private Spinner classSelection;

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    callingActivity = (StudentView) getActivity();

    populateClassList();

    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_student,null);

    final EditText editName = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.name_field);
    final EditText editAge =  dialogView.findViewById(R.id.age_field);
    final EditText editEmail = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.email_field);

    classSelection = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.class_spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, classList);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    classSelection.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    classSelection.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String d = (String) parent.getSelectedItem();

            Log.v("DialogRegisterStudent",d);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

The populateClassList() method populates an ArrayList called classList perfectly fine.

Is this an issue with the Spinner being contained within a DialogFragment?

Comment: Any error log ?

Comment: No error logs. When I look in Logcat there aren't any logs at all when I try to select an item from the dropdown.

Comment: Can you try to set breakpoint to `String d = (String) parent.getSelectedItem();` line ? `parent.getSelectedItem();` is showing any `String` ?

Comment: For some reason, the debugger doesn't even get to that breakpoint, and thus is not assigning the String value.

Comment: Can you show full code ? For example: where is your layout inflater code ? I mean `dialogView`.

Comment: @CagriYalcin the layout inflator code is nothing custom. I am using the one that is built into Android. Basically, in the activity where I am calling the DialogFragment from, I say DialogRegisterStudent dialog = new DialogRegisterStudent ();    and then dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "");

Comment: You want to show `DialogRegisterStudent` inside `AlertDialog` or `Activity` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to give a quick update about the situation right now. In my code, I am using an AlertDialog builder to build the dialog. After reading up on some stuff online, I found out since I am doing using the AlertDialog.builder, I can just move my code into the Activity rather than using a DialogFragment class as a container. In the activity, there is a Floating Action Button (FAB) which inflates the AlertDialog. Once I moved all the code from the DialogRegisterStudent class into the FAB's onClick method, the AlertDialog inflated and the spinner worked properly. Now, I am not sure why this works, but this has solved my problem.

Thanks to everyone who responded to my question, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using onCreateView() instead of onCreateDialog():

https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-dialogfragment#usage

Answer (score 0):

I've tried exactly the above code but i used `onViewCreated` instead.
I'm using data binding instead of finding view by Id but you can use it and it will work exactly the same.

Also this may seem obvious (although it took me some time - because by default i use `Log.d` ) but you're using `Log.v` (verbose), so make sure the Logcat level is set to verbose.

So to recap, move your code to `onViewCreated`, and make sure you're using the right level in Logcat.

here is the code that is working perfectly:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    String[] classList = {"1","2","3"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, classList);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    binding.spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    binding.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String d = (String) parent.getSelectedItem();

            Log.v("DialogRegisterStudent",d);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Does this work with a DialogFragment? I am using the code you provided and now it doesn't seem to be pulling up the layout. When the Dialog is being created, the screen just tints grey and doesn't display any layout.

Comment: @AnirudhKumar can you check and see if the new edit works for you ? also make sure you're using data binding - and if not then change `binding.spinner` to the variable of your spinner.

Comment: Do I also need an onCreateView() method, or is it just enough to replace the onCreateDialog()? Also, does onViewCreated work with an Alert Dialog?

Comment: You don't need `onCreateDialog` you just need to replace it with `onCreateView` and don't forget to add the above code to  the `onViewCreated`. As for the alert dialog, the code you wrote above is for a dialog fragment not an alert dialog, and the above code should work perfectly fine with it